# How to assign values for check boxes for a formula calculation which includes a text box in the formula

Tags: c#

I am a new programmer learning to code in C# and I have an C# assignment to be finished and for that I need to make some formulas to calculate rent for tours and for that I decided to use text boxes and check boxes in C# but I cant figure out how to make a formula with the combination of check boxes and a text box.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.Text = "50000";
    checkBox2.Text = "250000";
    checkBox3.Text = "2500";
    checkBox4.Text = "10000";
    checkBox5.Text = "1500"; 

    if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked && 
        checkBox2.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {

    }                            
}
```

[image: The form which i created for the calculation of rent]

Comment: You check which checkbox is checked by using `checkBoxName.Checked` and then set a value.. You'll end up with something like `(vehicle + driver) * duration` or something similar

Comment: @BiesiGrr I want to make this formula with IF statement and for that how can i give the code the above mentioned code is what i am trying to do assign some values to checkboxes and add the total amount with the assigned values of checkboxes and the values entered in the text box

Comment: Well what are you actual formulas for calculating the rent? It's not clear from your code sample what those strings representing numbers are for, and they don't appear anywhere on the form.

Comment: @RufusL the formula i am trying to create is, if i selected "checkbox 1" in Select Vehicle group box and "check box 5" in Driver Selection group box and with the selected checkboxes i multiply the value for number of days which is entered in "textbox2" which is displayed near the Total Value label

Comment: One thing to do one be to give meaningful names to the controls - you mention _textbox2_ & it really means nothing to us. Why are you changing the Text to the check boxes? Also it looks like RadioButtons would be more appropriate than checkboxes as you only want one option from each group.

Comment: @PaulF yes radio buttons would be appropriate but my problem is i dont know how to make a formula with the combination of textboxes and radio buttons

Comment: The type of control has little to do with creating a formula. To create the formula, you need to know all it's possible inputs and how they should be combined to produce the output. This could be done in a method, like `public int GetTotalValue(int vehicleValue, int driverValue, int rentDuration) { // return some value based on the input}` The trick is getting the state of your controls and determining what values they should represent when passed to your method with the forumula. Once you know that, then you would just do `totalValue.Text = GetTotalValue(carNumber, driverNumber, rentNumber);`

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by your question. Biesi Grr's first comment tells you exactly what to do - based on the checkbox/radio selection you allocate a value for the daily cost per car - similar for with/without driver. The contents of the textbox are converted to a number of days. The formula is given in the comment. You could use the Click event of the radio buttons to set the required rates rather than check the state of each button.

Answer (score 0):

The type of control has little to do with creating a formula. To create the formula, you need to know all it's possible inputs and how they should be combined to produce the output. This could be done in a method, for example:

```
private int GetTotalValue(int vehiclePrice, int driverPrice, int rentDuration)
{
    // This is where your formula would go
    return (vehiclePrice + driverPrice) * rentDuration;
}
```

The trick then, is to convert the state of the form controls into values that you can plug into the method. One way to do this (not necessarily the best way, but probably easiest to understand when you're starting) is to check the value of each control and set the appropriate value in the `Click` event for your `Submit` button.

For the rent duration, we can use the `int.TryParse` method, which takes in a string and an "out" int parameter, and returns true if the string is a valid integer, or false if it's not. When it exits, if the conversion was successful, the out parameter will contain the int value.

For the other controls, we could use simple `if / else if` statements to determine which control was checked, and then set our value accordingly. In this example, we're using temporary variables inside the click event to store the value for each parameter to the method. If none of the required controls are checked, we can show a message to the user and wait for them to finish filling out the form.

In this example I used radio buttons (and used the `opt` prefix, which is a naming convention from a long time ago that I'm not sure still exists - they used to be called option buttons):

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Validate that rent textbox contains a number
    int rentDuration;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtRentDuration.Text, out rentDuration))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for rent duration");
        return;
    }

    // Determine vehicle price based on which option was selected
    int vehiclePrice;
    if (optToyotaPrado.Checked) vehiclePrice = 50000;
    else if (optRollsRoyce.Checked) vehiclePrice = 250000;
    else if (optSuzikiWagonR.Checked) vehiclePrice = 2500;
    else if (optToyotaCorolla.Checked) vehiclePrice = 10000;
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a vehicle");
        return;
    }

    // Determine driver price
    int driverPrice;
    if (optWithDriver.Checked) driverPrice = 1500;
    else if (optWithoutDriver.Checked) driverPrice = 0;
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a driver option");
        return;
    }

    // Finally set the text to the return value of our original method,
    // passing in the appropriate values based on the user's selections
    txtTotalValue.Text = GetTotalValue(vehiclePrice, driverPrice, rentDuration).ToString();
}
```

Comment: the above code works until the GetTotalValue comes it shows an error saying non-invocable member 'Form1.GetTotalValue' cannot be used like a method

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Where did you define the method?

Comment: I defined the method in the submit button code area

Answer (score 0):

As Rufus said, I'd go with RadioButtons, instead of CheckBoxes.  Set the Tag property of the RadioButtons to the vaule you want associated with them and then use a function like this to get the value of the checked item.  Just pass in the GroupBox to the function and get back the value of the checked RadioButton.

```
 private int GetGroupBoxValue(GroupBox gb)
    {
        int nReturn = 0;
        foreach (Control ctl in gb.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
            {
                if (((RadioButton)ctl).Checked)
                {
                    nReturn = Convert.ToInt32(ctl.Tag);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return nReturn;
    }
```

Now all you have to do is use the excellent code Rufus provided for checking for an integer in the rentDuration TextBox and you're golden.